# How to check internet connectivity in Linux machine via terminal

Tags: linux, vmware

I set up a Linux environment in my windows machine via **VMware**. But once I've opened the firefox browser and tried to open google, got the error **server not found**. Not sure if my internet is working or not?

[image]

Can anyone tell me, **how to check the internet is working in my Linux machine or not via Linux terminal?**

Comment: You probably want to ask such questions/search for answers on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

I like to just paste `ping 8.8.8.8` in the terminal. If I get a reply internet is probably working. Next step is to `ping google.com` to see if my DNS is working.

Comment: when I ran `ping google.com` i got error `ping: unknown host google.com`

Comment: if `ping 8.8.8.8` worked, that means you should set up a DNS server.